# How to cluster a node js app without http server?

Tags: node.js, scaling

I try to learn about clustering, but all the examples use some http server.

My app uses multiple ws ( websocket ) client instances which are initialized inside to login to a server.

On top level I just want node js to use multiple cores without duplicating the connections, file logs, and other logs from the app.

```
const cluster       = require('cluster')
const config        = require('../config.json').sys
const core          = require('./test')

process.title = config.title
;(async () => {

if (cluster.isMaster){ 

    for (let i = 0; i < require('os').cpus().length; i++) cluster.fork()

    await core() // app i want to start

} 


})()
```

Would this now still benefit from all cpu's?

Comment: A webSocket server is an http server as every webSocket connection starts with an http request before the protocol is "upgraded" to the webSocket protocol.

Comment: but I can't use it, the websockets are clients and login sessions are one per IP. the cluster module duplicates it. and all the file-logging with it.

Comment: So, what are you trying to cluster then if you don't want multiple webSocket clients?  The nodejs cluster module is for sharing incoming connections among multiple processes.  That's what it does.  You have to define what you're trying to share among multiple processes before anyone could have any idea how to help.

Comment: I thought it was made to just cluster the entire application to use all cpu's.

Comment: Use all CPUs to do what?  The work to be done has to be broken into pieces that can be split among processes to use any sort of clustering or threading.

Comment: more specifically, the 5 websockets have to handle many incoming messages per second, but I am only allowed to hold 1 session per websocket or otherwise i get a forcedLogout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221301/discussion-between-btj84vvnnl2gh9gc-and-jfriend00).

Comment: You could create a processing queue and a set of worker processes for processing queued messages.  The master process could receive all the messages and put each one in the queue.  The worker processes then grab a message from the queue, process it, then repeat.  There isn't an automatic way to do this.  You will have to code it.

Comment: Can each of the 5 webSocket clients be put in different processes as a simple first step?

Comment: Thanks you so much, this information means a lot to me, as I thought about splitting each part into worker processes too. This seems like an interesting approach.
It involves also identifying and routing the incoming messages to the correct callbacks. It's using protobuffers.
> Can each of the 5 websocket...
yes that could be done too! good idea. and way simpler than the worker processes.

Comment: Would the process approach involve just using the fork() function once per module?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the process approach"?  You could create worker processes with `.fork()` if that's what you had in mind.